# PHP PDO sqlsrv Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver, sqlsrv

Hi I have wampserver 64 version 2.5, php version 5.5.12 and my operating system windows 10

I downloaded the sqlsrv drivers and I put it here in the directory 

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext`

and I paste this in my php.ini,

`extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`

the php.ini is located here `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

when I restart the services this is the error will pop up

[image]

I don't know how to fix this or is there something wrong that i miss ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no 64bit PHP compatible SQL Server library. You will have to install WAMPServer 32bit. This is not a WAMPServer limitation, its just that Microsoft has not yet completed the 64 bit PHP extension.

Probably they were waiting for PHP7 which is the first truly 64bit version of PHP

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply..if I will move to 32bit wampserver then my o.s is  64 bit am I not get into trouble  ?

Comment: No Windows 64bit OS will run 32bit and 64bit programs. WAMPServer 32bit definitely runs on Windows 64bit OS

Comment: your answer is useful

Comment: But you will have to make sure you have installed the 32 versions of all the required MSVC Runtime libraries [See this doc](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)